# What's the most scalable solver of this problem?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Consider the following optimisation problem that its size is parameterised by $n$ (width) and $m$ (depth):

Find $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ that minmises:
$$
\min \Big[w_1x_1^0 + w_2x_2^0 + \ldots + w_nx_n^0 \Big]
$$

Subject to:

$$
b^1_{\min} \le w_1x_1^1 + w_2x_2^1 + \ldots + w_nx_n^1 \le b^1_{\max}
$$
$$
b^2_{\min} \le w_1x_1^2 + w_2x_2^2 + \ldots + w_nx_n^2 \le b^2_{\max}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
b^m_{\min} \le w_1x_1^m + w_2x_2^m + \ldots + w_nx_n^m \le b^m_{\max}
$$

Where:

- $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ are variables that we must tune (by assigning real numbers to them) in order to solve the optimisation problem above.
- for any $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le j \le m$, $x_i^j$ is a constant real number, and $b^j_{\min}, b^j_{\max}$ are bounds.

  Note that superscript $^j$ is not an exponent, but a second index.  I thought it would be more readable to write $x_i^j$ than $x_{i,j}$.

***Question:*** What's the best asymptotic worst run-time and space that we can get for a solver of this problem?

E.g. can it get as low as $O(nm)$?  if not, what's the lowest we can achieve?

Comment: This is a linear programming problem, it seems. Consider using the Simplex algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of linear programming, so you can solve it with any LP solver.

Any instance of linear programming can be represented in this form.  For instance, minimize $c^\top w$ subject to $Aw \le b$ can be represented by setting $b^i_\max = b_i$, $x^i_j = A_{i,j}$, $b^i_\min=-\infty$, $x^0_j=c_j$.  Therefore, you can't expect any special-case algorithm that is more efficient than general-purpose linear programming.

The worst-case complexity of linear programming is polynomial but a bit [messy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Interior_point), but in practice it is often very efficient on real-world instances.